# Can't declare variable in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to listen to an event the MenuControl which is on a dummy gameobject with game controls to control inactivate the mouse controls if the menu is open. The action of opening a menu would trigger this event. The listener (in this case the character controller) would then stop the movement script (freeing up the cursor) in the movement script. **I can't seem to be able to declare an instance of a class from another script.** For some reason it yells at me when I try to declare an instance of the MenuControl Class. Please help.

```
public MenuControl menuControl;
```

Yields message:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MenuControl' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

The script for MenuControl:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

    public class MenuControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Canvas[] canvas;
        private float timePassed = 0f;

        public float delayTime = .1f;
        public KeyCode MenuKey = KeyCode.M;
        // Use this for initialization
        public delegate void OnMenuOpen(bool menuOpen); // declare new delegate type
        public event OnMenuOpen notifyMenuOpenObservers; // instantiate an observer set


        void Start()
        {
            canvas = FindObjectsOfType<Canvas>();
            canvas[1].enabled = false;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {

        }
        public void ToggleView()
        {
            print("hello world");


        }
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
            if (Input.GetKey(MenuKey))
            {

                if (timePassed > delayTime)
                {
                    canvas[1].enabled = !canvas[1].enabled;
                    canvas[0].enabled = !canvas[0].enabled;
                    if (!canvas[1].enabled)
                    {
                        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                        Cursor.visible = false;
                        notifyMenuOpenObservers(false);
                    }
                    else if (canvas[1].enabled)
                    {
                        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                        Cursor.visible = true;
                        notifyMenuOpenObservers(false);
                    }
                    timePassed = 0;
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

The containing script:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (Rigidbody))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CapsuleCollider))]
    public class RigidbodyFirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class MovementSettings
        {
            public float ForwardSpeed = 8.0f;   // Speed when walking forward
            public float BackwardSpeed = 4.0f;  // Speed when walking backwards
            public float StrafeSpeed = 4.0f;    // Speed when walking sideways
            public float RunMultiplier = 2.0f;   // Speed when sprinting
            public KeyCode RunKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;
            public float JumpForce = 30f;
            public AnimationCurve SlopeCurveModifier = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(-90.0f, 1.0f), new Keyframe(0.0f, 1.0f), new Keyframe(90.0f, 0.0f));
            [HideInInspector] public float CurrentTargetSpeed = 8f;

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            private bool m_Running;
#endif

            public void UpdateDesiredTargetSpeed(Vector2 input)
            {
                if (input == Vector2.zero) return;
                if (input.x > 0 || input.x < 0)
                {
                    //strafe
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = StrafeSpeed;
                }
                if (input.y < 0)
                {
                    //backwards
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = BackwardSpeed;
                }
                if (input.y > 0)
                {
                    //forwards
                    //handled last as if strafing and moving forward at the same time forwards speed should take precedence
                    CurrentTargetSpeed = ForwardSpeed;
                }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
                if (Input.GetKey(RunKey))
                {
                    CurrentTargetSpeed *= RunMultiplier;
                    m_Running = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_Running = false;
                }
#endif

#if !MOBILE_INPUT

    }
#endif

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
public bool Running
            {
                get { return m_Running; }
            }
#endif
        }


        [Serializable]
        public class AdvancedSettings
        {
            public float groundCheckDistance = 0.01f; // distance for checking if the controller is grounded ( 0.01f seems to work best for this )
            public float stickToGroundHelperDistance = 0.5f; // stops the character
            public float slowDownRate = 20f; // rate at which the controller comes to a stop when there is no input
            public bool airControl; // can the user control the direction that is being moved in the air
            [Tooltip("set it to 0.1 or more if you get stuck in wall")]
            public float shellOffset; //reduce the radius by that ratio to avoid getting stuck in wall (a value of 0.1f is nice)
        }


        public Camera cam;
        public MovementSettings movementSettings = new MovementSettings();
        public MouseLook mouseLook = new MouseLook();
        public AdvancedSettings advancedSettings = new AdvancedSettings();


        private Rigidbody m_RigidBody;
        private CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;

        private float m_YRotation;
        private Vector3 m_GroundContactNormal;
        private bool m_Jump, m_PreviouslyGrounded, m_Jumping, m_IsGrounded;
        public KeyCode OpenKey = KeyCode.E;
        public KeyCode ForwardKey = KeyCode.F;

        public float distanceToForward=1.2f;

        private bool screenFrozen = false;
        public GameObject roomManager;
        public MenuControl menuControl;

        public Vector3 Velocity
        {
            get { return m_RigidBody.velocity; }
        }

        public bool Grounded
        {
            get { return m_IsGrounded; }
        }

        public bool Jumping
        {
            get { return m_Jumping; }
        }

        public bool Running
        {
            get
            {
 #if !MOBILE_INPUT
                return movementSettings.Running;
#else
                return false;
#endif
            }
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            m_RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

            mouseLook.Init (transform, cam.transform);





        }


        private void Update()
        {
            RotateView();

            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = true;
            }
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            GroundCheck();
            Vector2 input = GetInput();

            if ((Mathf.Abs(input.x) > float.Epsilon || Mathf.Abs(input.y) > float.Epsilon) && (advancedSettings.airControl || m_IsGrounded))
            {
                // always move along the camera forward as it is the direction that it being aimed at
                Vector3 desiredMove = cam.transform.forward*input.y + cam.transform.right*input.x;
                desiredMove = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desiredMove, m_GroundContactNormal).normalized;

                desiredMove.x = desiredMove.x*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed;
                desiredMove.z = desiredMove.z*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed;
                desiredMove.y = desiredMove.y*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed;
                if (m_RigidBody.velocity.sqrMagnitude <
                    (movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed*movementSettings.CurrentTargetSpeed))
                {
                    m_RigidBody.AddForce(desiredMove*SlopeMultiplier(), ForceMode.Impulse);
                }
            }

            if (m_IsGrounded)
            {
                m_RigidBody.drag = 5f;

                if (m_Jump)
                {
                    m_RigidBody.drag = 0f;
                    m_RigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(m_RigidBody.velocity.x, 0f, m_RigidBody.velocity.z);
                    m_RigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, movementSettings.JumpForce, 0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
                    m_Jumping = true;
                }

                if (!m_Jumping && Mathf.Abs(input.x) < float.Epsilon && Mathf.Abs(input.y) < float.Epsilon && m_RigidBody.velocity.magnitude < 1f)
                {
                    m_RigidBody.Sleep();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_RigidBody.drag = 0f;
                if (m_PreviouslyGrounded && !m_Jumping)
                {
                    StickToGroundHelper();
                }
            }
            m_Jump = false;
            if (Input.GetKey(OpenKey))
            {

                RaycastHit hit;
                Vector3 vec = cam.transform.forward;
                Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, Color.green);
                if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, vec, out hit, 100))
                {
                    //Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Door")
                    {
                        hit.collider.transform.parent.parent.SendMessage("OpenDoor");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(ForwardKey))
            {
               RaycastHit hit;
                Vector3 vec = cam.transform.forward;
                Vector3 currposition = transform.position;
                if (Physics.Raycast(currposition, vec, out hit, 100))
                {
                    float d = (hit.point - transform.position).magnitude;
                    if (distanceToForward < d)
                    {
                        float y = transform.position.y;
                        transform.position = new Vector3(
                            (hit.point * (d - distanceToForward) / d + transform.position * distanceToForward / d).x,
                            transform.position.y,
                            (hit.point * (d - distanceToForward) / d + transform.position * distanceToForward / d).z
                            );


                    }
                }
            }

        }



        private float SlopeMultiplier()
        {
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(m_GroundContactNormal, Vector3.up);
            return movementSettings.SlopeCurveModifier.Evaluate(angle);
        }


        private void StickToGroundHelper()
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_Capsule.radius * (1.0f - advancedSettings.shellOffset), Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                                   ((m_Capsule.height/2f) - m_Capsule.radius) +
                                   advancedSettings.stickToGroundHelperDistance, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Angle(hitInfo.normal, Vector3.up)) < 85f)
                {
                    m_RigidBody.velocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(m_RigidBody.velocity, hitInfo.normal);
                }
            }
        }


        private Vector2 GetInput()
        {

            Vector2 input = new Vector2
                {
                    x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
                    y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical")
                };
            movementSettings.UpdateDesiredTargetSpeed(input);
            return input;
        }


        private void RotateView()
        {
            //avoids the mouse looking if the game is effectively paused
            if (Mathf.Abs(Time.timeScale) < float.Epsilon) return;
            if (screenFrozen) return;

            // get the rotation before it's changed
            float oldYRotation = transform.eulerAngles.y;

            mouseLook.LookRotation (transform, cam.transform);

            if (m_IsGrounded || advancedSettings.airControl)
            {
                // Rotate the rigidbody velocity to match the new direction that the character is looking
                Quaternion velRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(transform.eulerAngles.y - oldYRotation, Vector3.up);
                m_RigidBody.velocity = velRotation*m_RigidBody.velocity;
            }
        }

        /// sphere cast down just beyond the bottom of the capsule to see if the capsule is colliding round the bottom
        private void GroundCheck()
        {
            m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_IsGrounded;
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_Capsule.radius * (1.0f - advancedSettings.shellOffset), Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                                   ((m_Capsule.height/2f) - m_Capsule.radius) + advancedSettings.groundCheckDistance, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                m_IsGrounded = true;
                m_GroundContactNormal = hitInfo.normal;
            }
            else
            {
                m_IsGrounded = false;
                m_GroundContactNormal = Vector3.up;
            }
            if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && m_IsGrounded && m_Jumping)
            {
                m_Jumping = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your script named `MenuControl` in the Editor? The name should match with the class name.....

Comment: Yup. But for some reason I can't seem to access it. I can declare some classes in other class, but not others. I'm confused

Comment: I worked around it by accessing the controller from the menu script, but really an event system would be better because I want to have different controllers

Comment: Ok. 1.What is the name o the script in which you are trying to access `MenuControl` from? 2.Where did you put that script in your project? 3.Where did you put `MenuControl` in your project? A screenshot to answer these questions will even be better.

Comment: MenuControl is in Assets/Scripts. RigidBodyFirstPersonController is in Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts and is posted above

Comment: Ok. See duplicate for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

MenuControl is a gameobject so it needs to be declared as a GameObject where you want to instantiate it.

```
public GameObject MenuControl;
```

Then you want to access the object's Script when you need properties on the object

```
MenuControl.GetComponent<MenuControl>().MyProperty
```

Comment: if I do that, then it underlines and gives the same error for but for the portion in angle brackets <MenuControl>

Comment: I noticed your MenuControl is not wrapped in a Namespace.

Wrap it with something like 

`namespace Assets.Scripts{ }` This way your other file will be able to find it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with namespace. The problem is because of location where both scripts are placed. This is Unity specific feature.